# How can I configure Jackson to serialize base classes first?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have some JSON schemas which exist in a hierarchy: A extends B extends C. I am generating Java classes from these using [jsonschema2pojo](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo) and they get generated into a matching class hierarchy.

Because of the way I am generating the classes, I don't have fine-grained control of which annotations can be applied to which fields (i.e. [`@JsonPropertyOrder`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonPropertyOrder.html))

When I serialize with Jackson, I get something like

```
{
    "propertyOfA": "razz",
    "propertyOfA": "jazz",
    "propertyOfA": "baz",
    "propertyOfB": "bar",
    "propertyOfC": "foo"
}
```

Which is correct since property order has no meaning in JSON. However, my actual messages are very long - thousands of characters - and when browsing the logs it would be much more convenient if the more generic attributes (those from the base schema, schema C), of which there are only a few, came first in the message.

The individual property order within a schema/class doesn't bother me so much, but it would be nice if I could get Jackson to descend the hierarchy first and then backtrack.

```
{
    "propertyOfC": "foo",
    "propertyOfB": "bar",
    "propertyOfA": "razz",
    "propertyOfA": "jazz",
    "propertyOfA": "baz"
}
```

I checked all of the `Feature`s and `MapperFeature`s and the only thing I found to influence the order was [`SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/MapperFeature.html#SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY).

Is there anything else I can do at the `ObjectMapper`-level, or otherwise without changing the class, to influence this order?

Comment: You could write and register a custom serializer as described [`here`](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply [mixin](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations) annotations on a class outside of its (generated) source file. E.g.

on a new file, define an interface:

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({"propertyOfC", "propertyOfB"})
public interface MixinA {
}
```

and register it with your `ObjectMapper`:

```
objectMapper.addMixIn(A.class, MixinA.class);
```

properties listed in this order annotation go first so you may skip properties of A.

Comment: Thank you very much! I would like to apply this mixin to all targets, so I have written my own `MixInResolver` and I'm calling `setMixInResolver` rather than `addMixIn` but this was incredibly helpful.